# Keras save_weights/load_weights round trip failing. How to save and load weights?

Tags: keras

I am using the class api to subclass a model based on keras.models.Model.

Is there some trick to getting the save_weights working?

Am seeing errors like

ValueError: Layer #0 (named "dense_S") expects 0 weight(s), but the saved weights have 2 element(s).

Am trying by_name=True and False.

EDIT: it seems that calling predict once, with ANY data, is needed to build the layers for some reason. It would be interesting to here a proper explanation from anyone who knows more.

Comment: Please include code that reproduces this problem.